# aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers vs maxRequestLength

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, json-deserialization

I am running into errors like **The JSON request was too large to be deserialized.**.

Quick search on stackoverflow tells you that you should set appSetting **aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers** to be higher to fix the issue. However, the [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh975440(v=vs.120).aspx) documentation on the appSettings says

```
  Caution
  Setting this attribute to too large a number can pose a security risk.
```

I would expect that you are cautioned against setting this value to higher numbers to prevent anyone from submitting large payloads that could impact your system. However, given that I am already setting the value of **maxRequestLength** to a large number, will changing the **aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers** value have any other security implications?

I do not see how 1001 small json members could pose any more security threat that a single large json object.

Answer (score 7):

ASP.NET applications reject requests that have more than 1000 of these elements.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2661403

The Microsoft security update that security bulletin MS11-100 addresses changes the default maximum number of form keys, files, and JSON members that ASP.NET will accept in a request to 1,000. This change was made to address the Denial of Service vulnerability that the Microsoft security bulletin [MS11-100 documents.](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/ms11-100)